# Storing Lambda in Class

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, inline

What is the best practice to use when one needs to store a lambda as a class member so that its invocation can be deferred? More specifically, is it safe to store the lambda passed to the class `deferred_lambda` in the code listing below as a reference? If not, would it be safe if I were to store the the lambda in `deferred_lambda` as a value instead of as a reference?

Finally, can I expect to incur a performance penalty in comparison to a regular function call with g++ for storing the lambda as a class member in this way? That is, would using `deferred_lambda.invoke()` be slower than a call to `operator()` on some dummy struct that would implement the same operations?

With g++, I noticed that the size of the lambda increases as I use more captured variables. I suppose that this is to be expected, since to my understanding, the compiler internally generates a struct for the lambda that contains the necessary captured variables as members. This observation is what led to the question that I am now asking, since storing lambdas by value may be more expensive in terms of time and memory than storing references to them would.

```
template <class Func>
class deferred_lambda
{
    Func& func_;
public:
    deferred_lambda(Func func) : func_(func) {}
    void invoke() { func_(); }
};

template <class Func>
deferred_lambda<Func> defer_lambda(Func func)
{
    return deferred_lambda(func);
}

void foo()
{
    int a, b, c;
    auto x = defer_lambda([&]() { a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; });
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you'd store a _reference_ to a function object.

Comment: `would using deferred_lambda.invoke() be slower than a call to operator() on some dummy struct that would implement the same operations?` well, that's what a lambda _is_, anyway.

Comment: As I describe in my question, the function object can become large as more captures variables are used.

Comment: @void-panter: Yea, but what's three `int`s? Or, in fact, three _references_ to `int`s?

Comment: Point taken; I'll remove that part of my question.

Comment: That was a toy example; that if 10 or more variables were captured? Also, the size of a reference to an int will be the same as the size of the int.

Comment: Then you have ten references or objects. Still preferable -- usually -- to trying to wrestle with ownership, lifetime and safety around a function object. IMO.

Comment: `the size of a reference to an int will be the same as the size of the int` Chapter and verse, please.

Comment: Yes, but that's what my question is about.

Comment: Yes, I know... that's why we're talking about it.....?!

Comment: With g++ and on the x86 architecture, but not in general. std::cout << sizeof(int) << " " << sizeof(int&) << " " << sizeof(int*) << "\n";

Comment: No, indeed, not in general. In fact, even on that specific platform, it is unspecified as to whether any given reference requires _any_ storage at all (`8.3.2/4`).

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. I didn't mean for my statement to be a generality or requirement. In practice, the size of the lamdba does bloat as more references are captured -- even if they are references to ints. (Try printing out `sizeof(x)` and using fewer captured variables.) So if many `deferred_lambda` objects are created, I'd expect that storing a reference to the function object would be cheaper than storing the function object by value.

Comment: I'd expect that too. But then you balance that with "well, is it really worth it?"

Comment: If it helps, I haven't encountered any unexpected behavior from doing so in situations where the `deferred_lambda` object is destroyed in the method in which it is created. Admittedly, a bug resulting from this practice may be difficult to track down.

Comment: It seems highly likely that you're invoking UB in such a case. Dangling references and all that. However, the storage mechanism for the function object may mask it, yielding no adverse symptoms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> More specifically, is it safe to store the lambda passed to the class deferred_lambda in the code listing below as a reference?

No. That would be a dangling reference after `defereed_lambda()` has finished.

> If not, would it be safe if I were to store the the lambda in deferred_lambda as a value instead of as a reference?

Yes. But you still have to ensure variables captured by reference still live when executing the lambda.

> That is, would using deferred_lambda.invoke() be slower than a call to operator() on some dummy struct that would implement the same operations?

Probably not, there's no reason for it.

> This observation is what led to the question that I am now asking, since storing lambdas by value may be more expensive in terms of time and memory than storing references to them would.

It still has to be stored *somewhere*...

Answer (score 7):

I believe the way to store a lambda for later execution is to use a `std::function` object. Depending on the library implementation the `function` class should have the necessary constructors and convertors to have a lambda, or any other sort of functor or function, assigned to it for later execution.